# How do I Unit test/mock ElasticSearch

Tags: scala, unit-testing, elasticsearch

First off I'm using Scala and sbt for my application.

I'm using the elastic4s library's ElasticClient to connect to my ES instance. So basically I just need to be able to test these in my unit tests. Such as just verifying that my data actually made it into ES and things like that.

Would mocking ElasticSearch be the best way to go or is there a more efficient way of doing this? And how would I go about either of those?

I've found that you can set up a local client with ElasticClient.local but I can't seem to find many examples. We would like to go with this implementation so if you know how to use this I'd like to hear about it but if there are better or easier ways to complete this that would work.

Comment: Let me be purist, but *verifying that my data actually made it into ES* is not a unit test, it's *integration* test because you're checking how well one component (your code) plays with another (ES)

Answer (score 3):

In my own code, I recently wrote up a small Embeddable elastic search for testing. It stores things on Disk and then can delete the files after use. I use this to run my various elasticsearch unit test.

It make a single node elasticsearch cluster. This node supports the full elasticsearch API.

```
 /**
 * A simple embeddable Elasticsearch server. This is great for integration testing and also
 * stand alone tests.
 *
 * Starts up a single ElasticSearch node and client.
 */
public class EmbeddedElasticsearchServer
{
  public EmbeddedElasticsearchServer(String storagePath) {

    storagePath_ = storagePath;
    ImmutableSettings.Builder elasticsearchSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
      .put("http.enabled", "false")
      .put("path.data", storagePath_);

    node_ = new NodeBuilder()
      .local(true)
      .settings(elasticsearchSettings.build())
      .node();

    client_ = node_.client();
  }



  public Client getClient() {
    return client_;
  }


  public void shutdown()
  {
    node_.close();
  }

  public void deleteStorage() throws IOException
  {
    File storage = new File(storagePath_);

    if(storage.exists())
    {
      FileUtils.deleteDirectory(storage);
    }

  }

  private Client client_;
  private Node node_;
  private String storagePath_;
}
```

To use it, just call getClient and then you can use the Elasticsearch Java API just fine.

Comment: Really these are intergration tests.

Answer (score 2):

since [elastic search is java](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) and your code is too (or compatible) the best approach would be figure out a way to boot elastic search "embeddable" - just start their server up in your `@Before` method and shut it down / clear it in `@After`.

luckily for you, it seems like someone already had the exact same idea - https://orrsella.com/2014/10/28/embedded-elasticsearch-server-for-scala-integration-tests/

Comment: this link points to integration test. Is there any reference for unit tests? Thanks

Comment: @Bob I'm not sure that test is still unit if you need embedded database.

Answer (score 1):

For our ElasticSearch tests we use an always-on instance of ElasticSearch on our Jenkins build server that each test uses. For local tests, you have to fire up your local ElasticSearch. We use the rest interface, not the java api.

In order to make the unit tests parallelizable, we use an global, synchronized name pool (for index names). Each test can configure an index definition json, and if it is ok to run on an dirty (= already filled) index. A small test superclass (scalatest) will aquire an index name from the pool. If a clean index is required, an (maybe) existing one is deleted and the new one created. If the test accepts an dirty index, it is checked if the index definition is the same as the configured one. If not, the index is also re-created.

Depending on your test cases, this enables you to go with a few indexes that will be recreated once in a while, and being reused often by tests, speeding up test execution.

Answer (score 0):

I use junit + mock server (http://www.mock-server.com/), this open a Netty on localhost:9200 and listen incoming connection.

You must bind rules such as :

- "/" -> give ES version
- "/_search" -> send this JSON
- etc..

  ```
  @Rule
  public MockServerRule mockServerRule = new MockServerRule(9200, this);

  private MockServerClient mockClient;

  @Before
  public void setup() {

  mockClient.when(
          HttpRequest.request("/")
  ).respond(HttpResponse.response("{\"name\" : \"mock\", \"cluster_name\" : \"mock\", \"version\": { \"number\" : \"2.4\"}}").withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));

  mockClient.when(
          HttpRequest.request()
          .withPath("*/_count")
  ).respond(HttpResponse.response("{\"count\": 0}").withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));

  mockClient.when(
          HttpRequest.request()
                  .withPath("*/_search")
  ).respond(HttpResponse.response("{\"hits\": {\"total\" : 0}}").withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));

  mockClient.when(
          HttpRequest.request()
  ).respond(HttpResponse.response("{\"ok\":\"2.4\"}").withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));
  }
  ```

This is not saving any data, it's a very simple mock. I am using it to test a Java Spark application that uses elasticsearch-hadoop plugin.

Of course, this is for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question without a physical networking facility:

An example using `SearchRequest` and `SearchResponse`

```scala
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.{RequestSuccess, Executor, Functor, Handler, JacksonSupport}
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.requests.searches.{SearchHit, SearchHits, SearchRequest, SearchResponse, Total}

def toSearchResponse(hits: Array[SearchHit]): SearchResponse = {
  val searchHits = SearchHits(Total(hits.size,""), 10, hits)
  // successful, failed, total
  val shards = Shards(1, 1, 1)
  SearchResponse(10L, //took
    false, // isTimedOut
    false, // isTerminatedEarly
    Map.empty, // suggest
    shards, // _shards
    None, // scrollId
    Map.empty, // _aggregationsAsMap
    searchHits) // hits
}

def jsonToHit(): SearchHit = {
    val json = JacksonSupport.mapper.readTree(
      """{
        "_id": "b141597ad13f9a3af3879c5ea64761f7",
        "_index": "dev_local_collectr_person",
        "_score": 4.9972124,
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_source": {"some":"elasticsearch response"}
      }"""
    )

    JacksonSupport.mapper.treeToValue[SearchHit](json)
}

val mockElasticClient = mock[ElasticClient]
val searchResponse = toSearchResponse(Array(jsonToHit))
val futureResponse = Future {
    RequestSuccess[SearchResponse](200, Some(""), Map.empty, searchResponse)
}

(mockElasticClient.execute(_: SearchRequest)(
    _: Executor[Future],
    _: Functor[Future],
    _: Handler[SearchRequest,SearchResponse],
    _: Manifest[SearchResponse])
).expects(*, *, *, *, *).returning(futureResponse)
```

This can be conceptualized generically to something like this

```
def to[U](hits: Array[SearchHit]): U = {
  val searchHits = SearchHits(Total(hits.size,""), 10, hits)
  // successful, failed, total
  val shards = Shards(1, 1, 1)
  U( ... ) 
}

val mockElasticClient = mock[ElasticClient]
val searchResponse = toSearchResponse(Array(jsonToHit))
val futureResponse = Future {
    RequestSuccess[U](200, Some(""), Map.empty, searchResponse)
}

(mockElasticClient.execute(_: T)(
    _: Executor[Future],
    _: Functor[Future],
    _: Handler[T,U],
    _: Manifest[U])
).expects(*, *, *, *, *).returning(futureResponse)
```

Where `T` is the Request Object passed into execute and `U` is the nested return object.

Some other sample T's:

- IndexRequest
- SearchRequest

Some other sample U's:

- IndexResponse
- SearchResponse

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = mock(SearchResponse.class);
SearchResponse scrollResponse = mock(SearchResponse.class);
when(analysisRestClient.search(any(), Mockito.any(RequestOptions.class))).thenReturn(searchResponse);
SearchHits searchHits = mock(SearchHits.class);
SearchHit searchHit = mock(SearchHit.class);
when(searchResponse.getHits()).thenReturn(searchHits);
when(searchHits.iterator()).thenReturn(Iterators.singletonIterator(searchHit));
EventDto eventDto = new EventDto();
when(searchHit.getSourceAsString()).thenReturn(JSON.toJSONString(eventDto));
when(searchHits.getTotalHits()).thenReturn(1L);
when(analysisRestClient.scroll(any(), Mockito.any(RequestOptions.class))).thenReturn(scrollResponse);
when(searchResponse.getScrollId()).thenReturn("ddd");
```